# Adicionar segundo elemento ao evento "click" no javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

possuo código em javascript que carrega dados ao clicar em um botão, gostaria de saber como posso fazer pra carregar essas mesma informações em outro botão, ou seja, gostaria de adicionar mais um elemento ao trecho:

```js
$(function () { $(".glyphicon-search"***SEGUNDO ELEMENTO AQUI***).click(function () {
```

Segue o código JAVASCRIPT

```js
$(function () { $(".glyphicon-search").click(function () {
var id_codigo = $(this).data('codigo');
var id_situacao = $(this).data('situacao');
        
$(".modal-body #id_codigo").val(id_codigo);
$(".modal-body #id_situacao").val(id_situacao);
})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seletor do jQuery aceita múltiplos elementos, basta separá-los por uma vírgula:

```
$("seletor1, seletor2, seletor3 etc.")
```